# Loading date into JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I had some problems loading a date into a `JTextField`. What mistakes did I make?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  try {

    for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
      if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
        break;
      }
    }
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewApplication.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewApplication.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewApplication.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewApplication.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
  //</editor-fold>

  /* Create and display the form */
  java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      new NewApplication().setVisible(true);
    }
  });

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
public class FormatedDate {
  Date dNow = new Date();
  SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz");
  String reportDate = ft.format(dNow);

  public void LoadDate() {
    jTextField3.setText(reportDate);
    System.out.println("Current Date: " + reportDate);
  }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please explain what problems you encountered.

Comment: I don't know how to load current date to jTextField. I am messed up with static and non-static.

Comment: First you have to create and add a text field to the frame before you can display a value. Post your `SSCCE` that shows a frame with a text field. If you don't know what a SSCCE is the search the forum of the web. The code you posted doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

1. get current date time with Date()

   ```
   //get current date time with Date()
      Date date = new Date();
      System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
      jTextField3.setText(dateFormat.format(date));
   ```
2. get current date time with Calendar()

   ```
   //get current date time with Calendar()
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      jTextField3.setText(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
   ```